# Changing label colors in bottom tableview cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

**What I want to achieve:**  Making all the labels in the bottom-most cell of a `UITableView` gray and changing them back to their original colors as it scrolls up. In other words, kind of a gradient effect, just that all label colors have to be gray.
**What I have achieved:**  Added the original colors in an array and trying to determine which cell is at the bottom (using `visibleCells`) and then changing its label colors. But a lot of that code depends on manually determining offsets and thus seems scary to me.
**What I have tried:** Adding a `CAGradientLayer`. But it makes the cell to fade away. I want the labels in the cell to turn gray. Similar, but not the same.
**Note:** The cell is a custom cell with labels, buttons and even a simple `UITableView`, I need to store the colors for all these somewhere and then apply gray color till the cell is at the bottom. Once it scrolls up, I would have to re-color all the subviews again.
Can anyone suggest a better approach for achieving all this?
**Added Question:** As suggested by @Bamsworld below, is there a blend mode which can help me achieve this, i.e. a blend mode which would render all underlying text in gray? I know of multiply blend mode, but have only a faint idea of others.

Comment: Can you post screenshot of screen? Because its totally scary to predict actual output you want.

Comment: Sorry, but even I don't have a screenshot. Its just like a fading effect seen at the end of some tables. The only difference being that, I don't want the cells to fade. I want all the inside labels to turn gray.

Answer (score 0):

Because **UITableViewDelegate** protocol conforms to **UIScrollViewDelegate** you can add the method **scrollViewDidScroll:** to detect when the table scrolls and handle any cell alterations from within this method.

Example: *(assuming a table view called testTable)*

```
// detect when it scrolls
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    // query visible cells and get how many
    int numCellsOnShow = [[testTable visibleCells] count];

    // get the cell to change at bottom of table (this will be the last one in the array of visible cells)
    UITableViewCell *cellToEdit = [[testTable visibleCells] objectAtIndex:numCellsOnShow - 1];
    cellToEdit.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];

    // revert top and second bottom cells to prevent cell aesthetic bleeding
    UITableViewCell *cellToRevert = [[testTable visibleCells] objectAtIndex:numCellsOnShow - 2];
    cellToRevert.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    UITableViewCell *topCell = [[testTable visibleCells] objectAtIndex:0];
    topCell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

}

In the above code I've only altered the title **textLabel** colour, however any number of changes/alterations could be performed.

Note: if your table view height is not a multiple of the tableViewCell height (assuming constant dimensions of cells within the table), you may decide to grey the bottom two cells, as the bottom cell can potentially be barely visible even though it is contained in the visibleCells array.

Comment: This is the same thing I managed to eke out at the onset. I have again edited my question. While achieving this was easy, I am facing problems for the next part. Anyways, thanks for your quick help. Appreciate it.

Comment: Ah I see now where you want to head. I think you are on the right track with some sort of gradient mask and tweak the blending modes. I'm not sure whether its worth looking at animatable properties to create some sort of illusion.